# Silverlight and wildcard ssl certificates

Tags: silverlight

Can Silverlight app work with wild card SSL certificates?

Eg. www.mywebsite.com, mysubdomain1.mywebsite.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can.

Tim Heuer has some information about this in relation to using Amazon S3's wildcard certificate.  Look near the bottom of the post.

[Updates to Amazon S3 and Silverlight](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/07/15/amazon-s3-and-silverlight-part-2.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Wildcard cert will maintain a secure connection between the server and end-user. But if you are using Silverlight to embed code within the site, then you'll  need to sign the .XAP files with a code signing certificate, in order to deploy it without any warning dialog box to warn users of avoiding untrusted sources.